# determine a vector type using string at runtime

Tags: c++11, c++17

I am trying to set the type of a vector or tuple using a string at runtime. I can use an if else but wondering if there are better options

```
string typestr;
cin>>typeStr
if(typeStr=="int")
        vector<int> sample;
else if(typeStr=="double")
        vector<double> sample;
...
```

For example, something like this would be great (an explanation of why this is difficult is also appreciated)

```
vector<auto> sample;
sample.push_back(5); // deduces to int
```

or something like

```
vector<typeStr> sample; //typestr using cin or some other run time component
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080790/create-objects-from-template-type-is-entered-by-user-input-c

Comment: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly with the vector?

Comment: I am trying to take inputs from a user for types in a tuple. I figured starting with a vector is easier.

Comment: @TrevorTippins thanks for the link, I had forgotten about user-defined types

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work, you need *subtype polymorphism* but templates provide a kind of *parametric polymorphism* which doesn't fit your purpose, a `std::vector<T>` and a `std::vector<U>` with `T != U` are two completely different types.

You could have a polymorphic data type, eg:

```
union DataType 
{
  int i;
  double d;
};

std::vector<DataType> values;
```

or with a complex data type with virtual methods but that would kill performance. Or you could move the template argument at a higher level, eg:

```
template<typename T> 
void process()
{
   std::vector<T> sample;
   sample.push_back(whatever);
   /* process */
}
```

Otherwise your best bet otherwise is to wrap the `std::vector<T>` in another type which could provide the polymorphism you need.

I'd like to know what's your exact problem though, since this could be an XY problem.

Comment: I added more clarification after some more analysis to better define my problem. Please let me know if this helps.